# Get currently selected value of UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have been googling how to get the currently selected value in UIPickerView, but everywhere it's mentioned using row:0 and so on.

I have a UIPickerView populated with string values like "One","Two", etc.

Now when I select a value to let's say "Two", is there anyway I can get this text.

Like in UITextView where it is _textview.text

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Every UIPickerView should have a delegate.

And you can ask this delegate for your picker's selected row title via something like:

```
  UIPickerViewDelegate *delegate = yourPickerView.delegate;
  NSString *titleYouWant = [delegate pickerView:yourPickerView titleForRow:[yourPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] forComponent:0];
```

(This is ***ASSUMING*** your component number is zero; your own implementation might be different).

[More documentation on the "`pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent`" method can be seen here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView%3atitleForRow%3aforComponent%3a).

Answer (score 16):

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    // selected value in Uipickerview in Swift
    let value=array[row]
    println("values:----------\(value)");

}
```

Comment: how does this answers the question? it's not even obj-c code

Comment: If every Objective-C question had an answer in Swift (of which there are nowhere near as many Q&A's), then the lives of many Swift developers would be a lot easier. Thank you @Quad!

Comment: Thanks for this Swift version

Answer (score 5):

First of all add UIPickerViewDatasource and UIPickerViewDelegate in .h file

then in .m add the line

```
self.myPickerView.delegate = self;
```

now assign array by its objects.

```
NSArray *arrOfAge = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@“one”,@”two”, nil];
```

This are delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [arrOfAge count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *titleRow;
    titleRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrOfAge objectAtIndex:row]];
    return titleRow;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    selectedRow = row;
}
```

This IBAction btnDone returns the selected row from pickerView.

```
- (IBAction)btnDone:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger num = [[self.myPickerView dataSource] numberOfComponentsInPickerView:self.myPickerView];
    NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString string];
    for(NSUInteger i =0;i<num;++i)
    {
        NSUInteger selectRow = [self.myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:i];
        NSString *ww = [[self.myPickerView delegate] pickerView:self.myPickerView titleForRow:selectRow forComponent:i];
        [text appendFormat:@"%@",ww];
        NSLog(@"%@",text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the UIPickerView has only one component (something similar to section for UITableView) you can retrieve the "index" selected with the following line:

```
NSInteger indexSelected = [myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
```

(change the parameter 0 if you have more than one component).

This is the index in your array of data (myArray), the same you used to return data from the delegate method, as in:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 return myArray[row];
}
```

(or similar delegate methods -attributedTitleForRow -viewForRow)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

you can use this code for getting current title

```
self.textview.text = self.pickerView(self.pickerViewOutlet, titleForRow: self.pickerViewOutlet.selectedRow(inComponent: 0), forComponent: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use an array to initialize the picker you can use:

```
let p0 = pickerArray[0][pickerViewOutlet.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
let p1 = pickerArray[1][pickerViewOutlet.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
let p2 = pickerArray[2][pickerViewOutlet.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]
```

etc.